# Issues Upgraging to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ide

Just curious how many people are actually running 2010 and what's your feedback so far?

- Can I run 2010 concurrently with 2008 without issues?
- Also, are 2008 projects 100% compatible with 2010 and if so should I just uninstall 2008?

***Thanks for any feedback.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've moved the whole development group for our project to VS2010 3 days after it came out. Before this I've been trying out the beta versions on my machine with some side projects.

From the experience I got I can say:

- VS 2010 can easily run alongside VS
  2008 on the same machine without any
  issues whatsoever.
- The projects
  created in VS 2008 can be opened in
  VS 2010. But when they are opened -
  they will be updated to the new
  format, and cannot be reopened in VS 2008. The changes aren't critical, so if it's necessary it is possible to
  revert these changes. Possible, bt
  not straightforward :)

This means that if you're working on a collaborative project, either the whole team moves to 2010, or you all stay with VS 2008. That doesn't mean you can't write your own projects in VS 2010 in parallel ^_^

**UPD:** I haven't met any projects that I wasn't able to convert using the conversion wizard. but just in case you can install VS 2010, convert your project, and see if it's all fine. If it is - work on it for a couple of days.. If you're completely satisfied - uninstall VS 2008 and feel good about it :D

Comment: Great feedback. I have a small team so migrating everyone over wouldn't be a huge disaster. Thanks again.

Comment: Any new features stand out on the team foundation side ...?

Comment: We don't use Team Foundation in our team. Instead use the regular VS versions, and use SVN for the code repository.. Don't know the reasons - this was set up before I joined the team :)
One VERY GOOD feature of Team System (that was also present in 2008) is Database Comparison.. Can compare the schema and data between two sql databases, and give you the upgrade scripts.. Don't know any other )

Comment: Right. We've been using VisualSVN and we're happy but based on what I've seen online with regards to Team Foundation is definately the way we want to go for future projects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run 2010 concurrently with 2008. I wouldn't bet that every 2008 project can be opened/converted to a 2010 project otherwise Microsoft would have never spent so much time making the conversion wizard. The conversion wizard also mentions you should back up the files prior to conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How's it running performance wise compared to 2008?

Comment: Performance wise I feel it's considerably faster. The memory footprint is lower, and moving to a WPF interface made it a lot more pleasant to work with, imo